# Can ssh client made to timeout if no data received AFTER a ssh connection is successfully established

Tags: perl, ssh

I am writing a script that executes a command remotely via SSH using perl. Timeout can happen when
a) SSH client is unable to connect
b) SSH client is able to connect but the remote command takes a lot longer (say > 5 minutes) to execute

For (a), theren is an option available in ssh client. For (b), I cannot find anything.
Thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, kill_ssh_on_timeout => 1, timeout => 5);
my $output = $ssh->capture({tty => 1, timeout => 300}, $cmd);
```

Though, read [the entry](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH#Timeouts) about timeouts on the module docs.

Answer (score 1):

`man ssh_config` suggests that `ServerAliveInterval` is what you're searching for:

```
ServerAliveInterval
     Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message through
     the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent
     to the server, or 300 if the BatchMode option is set.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.  ProtocolKeepAlives and
     SetupTimeOut are Debian-specific compatibility aliases for this option.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are loking for is a time-out wakeup functionality? If you are used to signals try POSIX::alarm(). Or check Perl module IPC::Run.